# Не получается подключится к серверу по ftp через FileZilla, соединение установлено, ожидание приглашения

Tags: сервер, ftp, filezilla

Не получается подключиться к своему серверу. Брандмауэры отключал, способ входа - нормальный, шифрование - ftp, хотя другие все тоже перепробовал, режимы передачи (пассивный, активный) тоже менял туды сюды. Программа - FileZilla, ответы искал - не нашёл, плохо искал что ли.

В ходе подключения происходит следующее:

```
Статус: Определение IP-адреса для localhost 
Статус: Соединяюсь с 127.0.0.1:8080... 
Статус: Соединение установлено, ожидание приглашения... 
Ошибка: Соединение прервано после 20 секунд неактивности 
Ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к серверу
Статус: Ожидание повтора...
```

Answer (score 0):

Для коннекта с ftp-сервером в таком случае помогает повторный вызов соединения через "Менеджер сайтов".